# How to count favorites and all data of an other table with JOIN

Tags: sql, database

I try to select the favorites for each wines in my database and all data from wines but with the group by obligation, I can't have data for wines which don't have a favorite_score, so do you know how to do please.

```
SELECT SUM(wine_id) as favorite_score, wines.*
FROM wines JOIN
     favorites
     ON favorites.wine_id = wines.id
WHERE wine_color in ('White') AND
      available = 1
GROUP BY wines.id
ORDER BY wines.id
```

This is my SQL request for instance and now this my DB diagram :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8iJj.png)

So, I want all data for each wine and favorite_score too for each one or 0 if there is no data corresponds on wines.id = favorites.wine_id
Sorry for my English, I'm French

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do a sum, because that will sum all the `wine_id`s and not the number of `wine_id`s in the table favorites.

for example, you have `wine_id = {50, 100,123}` and a `SUM(wine_id)` would be 273, but I assume that what you want is 3 instead. So based on that, the query I would do is as follows

```
select count(f.wine_id) as favorite_score, w.*
from wines as w
join favorites as f
on w.id = f.wine_id
WHERE w.wine_color in ('White') AND
      w.available = 1
group by w.id, w.price, w.certification_label, w.label_name, w.vintage, w.oenological_comment,
w.area, w.city, w.variety_of_wine, w.age_of_vineyard, w.soil, w.prunning, w.harvest,
w.vinification, w.quantity, w.barrel_fermentation, w.image_path, w.available, w.wine_color, 
w.award, w.award_path, w.extra_comment
order by w.id
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Also, don't forget that for the `count` to work you need to add all the other fields in the `group by`, so I would advice you to only take the necessary fields.

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I would, however thre is lot condition on Group By but it works and give me the right result.

Comment: @ApoSkunz well yes, you need a group by for each field you want to see in the select part of the query. That is why I would advice you to instead of select *, you just choose a few of the fields as necessary

Comment: Yes thank you of course but I need all fields, I  think another method is to group field of the same json format to reduce fields for the group by option. But Thank you so much :)